# Need different versions of Node Js in Linux server

Tags: node.js, linux, nvm

Can I install two different node js version in Linux server i.e- v10 and v14.

Also, Is it possible by setting a temporary path for nodejs 14 version by downloading it's tar in linux. I do not want to upgrade or use NVM.Please suggest.

Comment: [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: You can use docker , ig.

Comment: yes, you can. yes, it is possible. - What exactly do you want to achieve that you do not want to upgrade or use NVM? What should be suggested instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with `n`: https://github.com/tj/n
Automatically installs and switch to a node version for you, better experience than `nvm` in my case.